# Padding between divider line and error text in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

How can I set the padding between the `divider line` and the `error text` (marked with the question mark in the image) in a `TextInputLayout`? I tried adding the padding in the style specified as  `errorTextAppearance` but it had no effect.

[image]

EDIT: Here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="test.textinputlayouttest.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/Error">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter address"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="26dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the style:

```
<style name="Error" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">300dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you need padding only between the `divider line` and the `error text`

use the previous example just change 
`android:padding="26dp"` to - > `android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/usernameWrapper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/username"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:hint="Username"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: But this increases the bottom margin regardless of whether error text is visible or not

Answer (score 1):

You can get the error textview with

```
TextView textView = (TextView) inputLayout.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.textinput_error);
```

And modify the layout params.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this way.. I think this will work..

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/usernameWrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:padding="26dp"
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="Username"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Nope, this did not change the padding

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"` in inner EditText

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    style="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
    tools:text="Text"
    />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

works for version: `com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0`